# Failed to create JVM error code -4

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.0

I am running Android Studio on windows 7 32-bit. I have a jdk 7 installed on my machine. I have my JAVA_HOME set. When I fire a **echo %JAVA_HOME%**, it gives me the path which is set. I am getting the Java version when I type **java -version**. However I am getting the below error.

[image]

Can anyone tell me the solution?

Comment: Did you make any property changes in android studio?

Comment: Check your Java installation and in case you also might need to increase the memory that Android Studio requires. Hope it helps.

Comment: I have [answered on another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66532284/5376073) what was working for me.